# Vuexy y Laravel JWT Token se pierde al actualizar

Tags: laravel, reactjs, jwt, next.js

Estoy trabajando con el template Vuexy con nextjs y el backend en Laravel, estoy teniendo problemas para mantener la sesion, logré hacer que inicie sesión con jwt y todo funciona sin problemas, el tema es que cuando actualizo la página (F5) no me valida de nuevo la sesión.

Este es el mock que utiliza el template para validar la sesión ya abierta.

```
mock.onGet('/auth/me').reply(config => {
  // ** Get token from header
  // @ts-ignore
  const token = config.headers.Authorization

  // ** Default response
  let response = [200, {}]

  // ** Checks if the token is valid or expired
  jwt.verify(token, jwtConfig.secret, (err, decoded) => {
    // ** If token is expired
    if (err) {
      // ** If onTokenExpiration === 'logout' then send 401 error
      if (defaultAuthConfig.onTokenExpiration === 'logout') {
        // ** 401 response will logout user from AuthContext file
        response = [401, { error: { error: 'Invalid User' } }]
      } else {
        // ** If onTokenExpiration === 'refreshToken' then generate the new token
        const oldTokenDecoded = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true })

        // ** Get user id from old token
        // @ts-ignore
        const { id: userId } = oldTokenDecoded.payload

        // ** Get user that matches id in token
        const user = users.find(u => u.id === userId)

        // ** Sign a new token
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({ id: userId }, jwtConfig.secret, {
          expiresIn: jwtConfig.expirationTime
        })

        // ** Set new token in localStorage
        window.localStorage.setItem(defaultAuthConfig.storageTokenKeyName, accessToken)
        const obj = { userData: { ...user, password: undefined } }

        // ** return 200 with user data
        response = [200, obj]
      }
    } else {
      // ** If token is valid do nothing
      // @ts-ignore
      const userId = decoded.id

      // ** Get user that matches id in token
      const userData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users.find(u => u.id === userId)))
      delete userData.password

      // ** return 200 with user data
      response = [200, { userData }]
    }
  })

  return response
})
```

hice varias pruebas pero sigo pudiendo iniciar sesion... usar todo pero cuando actualizo se queda cargando y es por la sesion.

```
public function me()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
        }

        $userData = [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'role' => 'admin', // Customize this based on your user roles logic
            'fullName' => 'PEPE LEPOU', // Assuming the user's name is stored in the 'name' field
            'username' => 'Pepito', // Change this field as per your user model
            'email' => $user->email,
        ];

        return response()->json([
            'userData' => $userData,
            'accessToken' => Auth::refresh(),
            'refreshToken' => Auth::refresh()
        ]);
    }
```

en network me figura que hace una peticion a la funcion "me" de mi laravel... y luego otra con error 401:

```
Accept:
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:
gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:
es-419,es;q=0.9
Authorization:
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L2FwaS9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY5MTc3MzQ5NCwiZXhwIjoxNjkxNzc3MDk0LCJuYmYiOjE2OTE3NzM0OTQsImp0aSI6Ild3ZkE1ZFNseFJOUU5uWkoiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwicHJ2IjoiMjNiZDVjODk0OWY2MDBhZGIzOWU3MDFjNDAwODcyZGI3YTU5NzZmNyJ9.mkRw-T7kZXWrYB2eoLf4D9n_CxeynuwnD5Fm9uhzZNE
Connection:
keep-alive
Host:
localhost
Origin:
http://localhost:3000
```